# How to use system clipboard in VIM

Tags: linux, vim

Here is scenario, In VIM, I copy the string(e.g. `/home/redhat`) from the file, and then use this command `:! cd XXX`(the path I have copied from the buffer, in this case it should be `/home/redhat`).

My question is, what command should I use to paste the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `:`, you're in *command-line mode*. Like in *insert mode*, you can insert register contents at the cursor position by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, followed by the register name. So, if you simply *yanked* the `/home/redhat`, that would be `"` for the default register; for the system clipboard, use `+` instead.

In the command-line, you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to switch to the *command-line window*, in which you can use all Vim commands, like in any other buffer, so you could also paste via the usual `p` / `P` from normal mode.

Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor. The help topics for the commands mentioned here are `:help c_CTRL-R` and `:help c_CTRL-F`.

Comment: Thanks for your description, this is what I exactly look for

Answer (score 2):

`"+y` is copy from system clipboard in vim, and `"+p` is paste from system clipboard, you can map them to normal key bindings.

```
noremap <C-C> "+y
noremap <C-V> "+p
```

" Note that mapping `<C-V>` to paste from system clipboard conflicts with `vertical mode` I suggest you remap `vertical mode` to `<C-Q>`

```
noremap <C-Q>       <C-V>
```

for other mappings, you can check [mswin.vim](http://vim.cybermirror.org/runtime/mswin.vim)

If you do not care about system clipboards, `y` is copy and `p` is paste in normal mode.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the system clipboard at all for your use case:

```
:!cd <C-r>"
```

In insert mode and in Vim's command-line, `<C-r>{register}` inserts the content of that register at the cursor. Since you yanked `/home/redhat`, the content of the unnamed register, `"` (see `:help registers`), is `/home/redhat` and it's inserted right where you typed `<C-r>"`:

```
:!cd /home/redhat
```

FWIW, you can also insert the file path under the cursor without yanking and pasting:

```
:!cd <C-r><C-f>
```

Answer (score 0):

With `:new /path/to/file` you go to new file. Then paste the information with `P` (always out of mode Insert).